# Ubuntu Touch: Can't change keyboard input

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

I've tried to change keyboard input language. I'm Norwegian and missing the letters Æ Ø Å. Followed the method in release notes, but when i try to save after edit the OSK (/home/phablet/.config/maliit.org./server.conf) i get error: ".config/maliit.org./server.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing"

I also get error when apt-get upgrade: 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "nb_NO:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "nb_NO.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Someone knows what I've done wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$ sudo - phablet

To use the phablet user and then:
$ nano /home/phablet/.config/maliit.org./server.conf

Will ask you for the password: phablet

Use nano or vi and try to write the file.

Comment: Sorry, try better:
$ **sudo vi /home/phablet/.config/maliit.org/server.conf**


And then Restart

Comment: Please **edit** your answer rather than posting corrections as comments ;)